# AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api

I try to redirect the user to Google calendar and get his authorization so that I can combine events on his Google Calendar and my own calendar, but I can't get the TOKEN querystring somehow :(

```
Dim tokenURL As String = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl("http://localhost:54522/scripts/wbmodules/test.aspx/RetrieveToken", "http://www.google.com/calendar/hosted/mydomain.nl/", False, False)
```

I see login and password page but when I enter information and try to redirect to my own website, I get this error message

The page you requested can not be displayed. Another site was requesting access to your mydomain account, but the format of the request was incorrect.

***The parameter 'scope' is incorrect or missing.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the mistake is found, I was using the wrong 'scope' 
Instead of "http://www.google.com/calendar/hosted/mydomain.nl/"

I should have used more general term
"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/"

So the correct version is as follows

```
Dim tokenURL As String = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl("http://localhost:54522/scripts/wbmodules/test.aspx/RetrieveToken", "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/", False, False)
```